# vsftp change user ownership

Tags: ftp

In vsftpd, I would like to have user upload file directly to web directory(/var/www/site/) however, the web directory is owned by www user and group.

I know there is chown_username and such thing for anonymous user however that doesn't work for my case. What do I do in vsftp?

thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can add `local_root=/var/www/site/` in the vsftpd.conf file as the root directory ftp user.

Comment: that's not my problem. the problem is that the ftp directory is owned by www-user and ftp user is not allowed to write to it.

Comment: you can give the perm for the ftp user to access the folder using setfacl command

Comment: I am hoping for a vsftp solution. Now I am resorting to adding ftp user to www-data group, set umask to 002 in vsftp and have the web root dir group writtable.

Comment: Even when the user is added to www-data group and file is uploaded through FTP Client, the user and group id of this file is different from www-data user/group id. And the file is not accessible from the web browser.